# Why is LastOrDefault(predicate) in LINQ faster than FirstOrDefault(predicate)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, .net-core

### Introduction

While testing performance differences with certain LinQ functions today, I noticed, that `LastOrDefault(predicate)` was almost always faster than `FirstOrDefault(predicate)`, which got me a little interested, so i wrote some test cases, to test both functions against each other.

I created a list of `integer` values from 1 to 1 mil like this:

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
  {
    l.Add(i);
  }
```

and then wrote 2 methods `first()` and `last()`

```
 static void first(List<int> l)
{
  int e = l.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 500000);
  int z = l.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 500000);
  int d = l.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 500000);
  int v = l.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 500000);
  int f = l.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 500000);
}
```

which i put in a for loop to run 1000 times, wile setting a breakpoint with a condition to halt after the last iteration, but in every singe case I tested, `LastOrDefault` was faster.

### Test cases

- Both set to an element the middle of the list (`LastOrDefault` is nearly double as fast)
- Both set to an element with the same distance within the list (like 250k and 750k) - again `LastOrDefault` was faster
- Switch order of my my method calls (call `Last()` before `First()`) - no difference
- run both with their own lists instead of running both on the same list (again no difference)
- run one, close the app, reopen, run the other (still `LastOrDefault` is faster)
- set the predicate to an element, thats not in the list (still same)
- Change the predicate to multipe eligable objects (still same)
- create a descending list instead of an ascending one (no difference)

  **.Net Core version: 3.0**

Since the debugger can be inaccurate, I tried again with this code:

```
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    first(l);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    last(l);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

which also returned 34 sec for `FirstOrDefault` and 23 sec for `LastOrDefault`

[image]

### Question

**How come `LastOrDefault` is so significantly faster than `FirstOrDefault`in all my test cases ?**

Comment: And what is exactly the outcome? How did you test? Did you allow for warm-up time?

Comment: Since the enumerable is a list, I highly doubt there is any performance difference in the direction you are walking the list. It is either `0..end` or `end..0`. There is nothing more.

Comment: Probably because FirstOrDefault uses enumerator and MoveNext, and LastOrDefault uses inverse for loop (for List). Actually depends on the type and whether it has predicate.

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman I set up a net Core Console app, filled the list, set an breakpoint after that and then called both methods in a for loop for 1000 times and took the time my debugger returns when reaching the last iteration, which is 32,8 sec for ´FirstOrDefault´ and 16,7 sec for ´LastOrDefault´ @Caramiriel added Net Core information

Comment: @steve16351 I think this must be it. .NET Standard doesn't have `Last`'s optimization and `Last` takes about twice as long, as you'd expect, but I see the same as OP in .NET Core.

Comment: @RenéVogt Please see Rawling's answer. I was sure I ready it somewhere, it is in the .NET Core code base.

Comment: For future benchmarking, you might want to use a dedicated library like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) (no affiliation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[steve16351](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3911233/steve16351) pointed out in a deleted comment that, in .NET Core, [`Last`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Last.cs) has the following optimization:

```
if (source is IList<TSource> list)
{
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        TSource result = list[i];
        if (predicate(result))
        {
            found = true;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

but [`First`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/First.cs) does not and ends up running:

```
foreach (TSource element in source)
{
    if (predicate(element))
    {
        found = true;
        return element;
    }
}
```

It is quite possible that the accessing of the list elements by indexer is faster than using a `foreach` and iterator. By contrast, .NET Standard does not have this optimization for [`Last`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3155d0589fd23593), instead iterating through the complete input, and `Last` runs more slowly than `First` as you would expect.

Comment: Oh. I was already woundering why his comment disappeared so fast, after it looked like he was correct, but it was gone when I reloaded the page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing `ExecuteFirst` and `ExecuteLast` even changing their order of execution, and `LastOrDefault` takes always more than `FirstOrDefault`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            ExecuteFirst(ref stopwatch, ref numbers);
            stopwatch.Reset();
            ExecuteLast(ref stopwatch, ref numbers);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            ExecuteLast(ref stopwatch, ref numbers);
            stopwatch.Reset();
            ExecuteFirst(ref stopwatch, ref numbers);
        }
    }

    private static void ExecuteFirst(ref Stopwatch stopwatch, ref List<int> numbers)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        int first = numbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 500000);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("First: " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void ExecuteLast(ref Stopwatch stopwatch, ref List<int> numbers)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        int last = numbers.LastOrDefault(x => x == 500000);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Last: " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Output of `ExecuteFirst then ExecuteLast` version:

> ```
> First: 00:00:00.0056298
> Last: 00:00:00.0089494
> First: 00:00:00.0039494
> Last: 00:00:00.0084491
> First: 00:00:00.0041225
> Last: 00:00:00.0087664
> First: 00:00:00.0039685
> Last: 00:00:00.0083576
> First: 00:00:00.0064472
> Last: 00:00:00.0109716
> First: 00:00:00.0041366
> Last: 00:00:00.0111575
> First: 00:00:00.0039746
> Last: 00:00:00.0085590
> First: 00:00:00.0040453
> Last: 00:00:00.0083751
> First: 00:00:00.0057352
> Last: 00:00:00.0090655
> First: 00:00:00.0041225
> Last: 00:00:00.0081635
> First: 00:00:00.0042336
> Last: 00:00:00.0085277
> First: 00:00:00.0038742
> Last: 00:00:00.0088863
> First: 00:00:00.0039309
> Last: 00:00:00.0141321
> First: 00:00:00.0044766
> Last: 00:00:00.0088888
> First: 00:00:00.0044096
> Last: 00:00:00.0147227
> First: 00:00:00.0042950
> Last: 00:00:00.0177956
> First: 00:00:00.0064265
> Last: 00:00:00.0158906
> First: 00:00:00.0051914
> Last: 00:00:00.0177836
> First: 00:00:00.0067148
> Last: 00:00:00.0123487
> First: 00:00:00.0045096
> Last: 00:00:00.0113824
> First: 00:00:00.0040213
> Last: 00:00:00.0145903
> First: 00:00:00.0061554
> Last: 00:00:00.0123555
> First: 00:00:00.0047815
> Last: 00:00:00.0119132
> First: 00:00:00.0055103
> Last: 00:00:00.0141871
> First: 00:00:00.0069865
> Last: 00:00:00.0115481
> First: 00:00:00.0052736
> Last: 00:00:00.0167697
> First: 00:00:00.0062566
> Last: 00:00:00.0111363
> First: 00:00:00.0051245
> Last: 00:00:00.0120161
> First: 00:00:00.0044649
> Last: 00:00:00.0086359
> First: 00:00:00.0039902
> Last: 00:00:00.0089326
> First: 00:00:00.0070409
> Last: 00:00:00.0093965
> First: 00:00:00.0047403
> Last: 00:00:00.0143759
> First: 00:00:00.0052523
> Last: 00:00:00.0105465
> First: 00:00:00.0072541
> Last: 00:00:00.0113418
> First: 00:00:00.0064120
> Last: 00:00:00.0139322
> First: 00:00:00.0062902
> Last: 00:00:00.0173657
> First: 00:00:00.0068329
> Last: 00:00:00.0163935
> First: 00:00:00.0056465
> Last: 00:00:00.0100116
> First: 00:00:00.0057379
> Last: 00:00:00.0084148
> First: 00:00:00.0058303
> Last: 00:00:00.0167930
> First: 00:00:00.0065232
> Last: 00:00:00.0100014
> First: 00:00:00.0039309
> Last: 00:00:00.0093778
> First: 00:00:00.0047291
> Last: 00:00:00.0133724
> First: 00:00:00.0044344
> Last: 00:00:00.0095120
> First: 00:00:00.0044793
> Last: 00:00:00.0083334
> First: 00:00:00.0048849
> Last: 00:00:00.0091849
> First: 00:00:00.0042633
> Last: 00:00:00.0095615
> First: 00:00:00.0074706
> Last: 00:00:00.0081830
> First: 00:00:00.0046968
> Last: 00:00:00.0086369
> First: 00:00:00.0055665
> Last: 00:00:00.0088337
> First: 00:00:00.0045883
> Last: 00:00:00.0112508
> First: 00:00:00.0078855
> Last: 00:00:00.0149504
> First: 00:00:00.0065615
> Last: 00:00:00.0102155
> First: 00:00:00.0046303
> Last: 00:00:00.0104928
> First: 00:00:00.0063564
> Last: 00:00:00.0119335
> First: 00:00:00.0048461
> Last: 00:00:00.0092795
> First: 00:00:00.0042306
> Last: 00:00:00.0090954
> First: 00:00:00.0042236
> Last: 00:00:00.0090376
> First: 00:00:00.0039102
> Last: 00:00:00.0087163
> First: 00:00:00.0047897
> Last: 00:00:00.0093651
> First: 00:00:00.0051779
> Last: 00:00:00.0101453
> First: 00:00:00.0041795
> Last: 00:00:00.0086312
> First: 00:00:00.0039371
> Last: 00:00:00.0087337
> First: 00:00:00.0048348
> Last: 00:00:00.0114352
> First: 00:00:00.0049419
> Last: 00:00:00.0134430
> First: 00:00:00.0063191
> Last: 00:00:00.0096597
> First: 00:00:00.0041087
> Last: 00:00:00.0100510
> First: 00:00:00.0055977
> Last: 00:00:00.0122221
> First: 00:00:00.0046453
> Last: 00:00:00.0097579
> First: 00:00:00.0050965
> Last: 00:00:00.0108959
> First: 00:00:00.0061811
> Last: 00:00:00.0093178
> First: 00:00:00.0060297
> Last: 00:00:00.0085977
> First: 00:00:00.0040451
> Last: 00:00:00.0114430
> First: 00:00:00.0046424
> Last: 00:00:00.0118572
> First: 00:00:00.0064396
> Last: 00:00:00.0147170
> First: 00:00:00.0052414
> Last: 00:00:00.0108874
> First: 00:00:00.0045109
> Last: 00:00:00.0082625
> First: 00:00:00.0044640
> Last: 00:00:00.0136483
> First: 00:00:00.0049840
> Last: 00:00:00.0087787
> First: 00:00:00.0049482
> Last: 00:00:00.0138222
> First: 00:00:00.0055885
> Last: 00:00:00.0109636
> First: 00:00:00.0052437
> Last: 00:00:00.0130392
> First: 00:00:00.0053844
> Last: 00:00:00.0103824
> First: 00:00:00.0062271
> Last: 00:00:00.0125599
> First: 00:00:00.0043152
> Last: 00:00:00.0091548
> First: 00:00:00.0059537
> Last: 00:00:00.0125432
> First: 00:00:00.0057340
> Last: 00:00:00.0099097
> First: 00:00:00.0052127
> Last: 00:00:00.0087050
> First: 00:00:00.0045914
> Last: 00:00:00.0095816
> First: 00:00:00.0065290
> Last: 00:00:00.0090501
> First: 00:00:00.0045474
> Last: 00:00:00.0108880
> First: 00:00:00.0054650
> Last: 00:00:00.0092074
> First: 00:00:00.0042946
> Last: 00:00:00.0129336
> First: 00:00:00.0045581
> Last: 00:00:00.0172552
> First: 00:00:00.0058246
> Last: 00:00:00.0080876
> First: 00:00:00.0040249
> Last: 00:00:00.0112583
> First: 00:00:00.0047926
> Last: 00:00:00.0085989
> First: 00:00:00.0045357
> Last: 00:00:00.0088068
> First: 00:00:00.0039247
> Last: 00:00:00.0094145
> First: 00:00:00.0039182
> Last: 00:00:00.0085856
> ```

Output of `ExecuteLast then ExecuteFirst` version:

> ```
> Last: 00:00:00.0087140
> First: 00:00:00.0045242
> Last: 00:00:00.0082524
> First: 00:00:00.0040122
> Last: 00:00:00.0081924
> First: 00:00:00.0039598
> Last: 00:00:00.0081365
> First: 00:00:00.0041632
> Last: 00:00:00.0087045
> First: 00:00:00.0040455
> Last: 00:00:00.0082440
> First: 00:00:00.0041200
> Last: 00:00:00.0082281
> First: 00:00:00.0041470
> Last: 00:00:00.0087138
> First: 00:00:00.0039467
> Last: 00:00:00.0082286
> First: 00:00:00.0099966
> Last: 00:00:00.0159285
> First: 00:00:00.0059864
> Last: 00:00:00.0103221
> First: 00:00:00.0045370
> Last: 00:00:00.0102541
> First: 00:00:00.0042682
> Last: 00:00:00.0081628
> First: 00:00:00.0062049
> Last: 00:00:00.0130017
> First: 00:00:00.0046107
> Last: 00:00:00.0146495
> First: 00:00:00.0060628
> Last: 00:00:00.0140509
> First: 00:00:00.0042348
> Last: 00:00:00.0087499
> First: 00:00:00.0043035
> Last: 00:00:00.0119328
> First: 00:00:00.0053357
> Last: 00:00:00.0095866
> First: 00:00:00.0081749
> Last: 00:00:00.0157497
> First: 00:00:00.0065187
> Last: 00:00:00.0165949
> First: 00:00:00.0062613
> Last: 00:00:00.0139213
> First: 00:00:00.0058088
> Last: 00:00:00.0121819
> First: 00:00:00.0054371
> Last: 00:00:00.0095390
> First: 00:00:00.0070151
> Last: 00:00:00.0110936
> First: 00:00:00.0073251
> Last: 00:00:00.0104844
> First: 00:00:00.0058563
> Last: 00:00:00.0131254
> First: 00:00:00.0064146
> Last: 00:00:00.0100039
> First: 00:00:00.0045887
> Last: 00:00:00.0102629
> First: 00:00:00.0051754
> Last: 00:00:00.0086035
> First: 00:00:00.0041619
> Last: 00:00:00.0104485
> First: 00:00:00.0055513
> Last: 00:00:00.0097863
> First: 00:00:00.0047921
> Last: 00:00:00.0097700
> First: 00:00:00.0049790
> Last: 00:00:00.0129902
> First: 00:00:00.0049853
> Last: 00:00:00.0090255
> First: 00:00:00.0044574
> Last: 00:00:00.0085991
> First: 00:00:00.0061191
> Last: 00:00:00.0144359
> First: 00:00:00.0048091
> Last: 00:00:00.0133516
> First: 00:00:00.0056255
> Last: 00:00:00.0084006
> First: 00:00:00.0063759
> Last: 00:00:00.0193624
> First: 00:00:00.0062311
> Last: 00:00:00.0176409
> First: 00:00:00.0069601
> Last: 00:00:00.0168154
> First: 00:00:00.0069095
> Last: 00:00:00.0099649
> First: 00:00:00.0057600
> Last: 00:00:00.0087139
> First: 00:00:00.0040068
> Last: 00:00:00.0085248
> First: 00:00:00.0061416
> Last: 00:00:00.0085084
> First: 00:00:00.0043856
> Last: 00:00:00.0089587
> First: 00:00:00.0044830
> Last: 00:00:00.0093276
> First: 00:00:00.0043679
> Last: 00:00:00.0110072
> First: 00:00:00.0042437
> Last: 00:00:00.0126469
> First: 00:00:00.0042610
> Last: 00:00:00.0112851
> First: 00:00:00.0044525
> Last: 00:00:00.0146068
> First: 00:00:00.0067056
> Last: 00:00:00.0126607
> First: 00:00:00.0048659
> Last: 00:00:00.0083654
> First: 00:00:00.0062265
> Last: 00:00:00.0097216
> First: 00:00:00.0061381
> Last: 00:00:00.0089756
> First: 00:00:00.0042742
> Last: 00:00:00.0106504
> First: 00:00:00.0059941
> Last: 00:00:00.0129825
> First: 00:00:00.0052327
> Last: 00:00:00.0086158
> First: 00:00:00.0048668
> Last: 00:00:00.0087767
> First: 00:00:00.0040427
> Last: 00:00:00.0097813
> First: 00:00:00.0042703
> Last: 00:00:00.0086771
> First: 00:00:00.0051560
> Last: 00:00:00.0097772
> First: 00:00:00.0051117
> Last: 00:00:00.0086385
> First: 00:00:00.0050181
> Last: 00:00:00.0092713
> First: 00:00:00.0044719
> Last: 00:00:00.0094507
> First: 00:00:00.0041345
> Last: 00:00:00.0090835
> First: 00:00:00.0041929
> Last: 00:00:00.0101841
> First: 00:00:00.0045660
> Last: 00:00:00.0132945
> First: 00:00:00.0042977
> Last: 00:00:00.0102504
> First: 00:00:00.0041772
> Last: 00:00:00.0087283
> First: 00:00:00.0058613
> Last: 00:00:00.0095019
> First: 00:00:00.0058306
> Last: 00:00:00.0098703
> First: 00:00:00.0062143
> Last: 00:00:00.0143740
> First: 00:00:00.0058965
> Last: 00:00:00.0146650
> First: 00:00:00.0049196
> Last: 00:00:00.0101419
> First: 00:00:00.0045298
> Last: 00:00:00.0096505
> First: 00:00:00.0047797
> Last: 00:00:00.0107579
> First: 00:00:00.0059183
> Last: 00:00:00.0126266
> First: 00:00:00.0055267
> Last: 00:00:00.0126165
> First: 00:00:00.0054118
> Last: 00:00:00.0120701
> First: 00:00:00.0051365
> Last: 00:00:00.0153770
> First: 00:00:00.0053540
> Last: 00:00:00.0153887
> First: 00:00:00.0070967
> Last: 00:00:00.0130810
> First: 00:00:00.0058005
> Last: 00:00:00.0099139
> First: 00:00:00.0045073
> Last: 00:00:00.0086909
> First: 00:00:00.0050152
> Last: 00:00:00.0092414
> First: 00:00:00.0045098
> Last: 00:00:00.0081899
> First: 00:00:00.0039903
> Last: 00:00:00.0088524
> First: 00:00:00.0044292
> Last: 00:00:00.0085165
> First: 00:00:00.0041663
> Last: 00:00:00.0079039
> First: 00:00:00.0040911
> Last: 00:00:00.0083395
> First: 00:00:00.0041872
> Last: 00:00:00.0093267
> First: 00:00:00.0041617
> Last: 00:00:00.0092689
> First: 00:00:00.0042109
> Last: 00:00:00.0088358
> First: 00:00:00.0041233
> Last: 00:00:00.0081352
> First: 00:00:00.0046823
> Last: 00:00:00.0085252
> First: 00:00:00.0042007
> Last: 00:00:00.0083383
> First: 00:00:00.0041155
> Last: 00:00:00.0096344
> First: 00:00:00.0046664
> Last: 00:00:00.0110845
> First: 00:00:00.0047776
> ```